# Sorting arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, modulo

Write a static method in Java:

```
public static void sortByFour (int[] arr)
```

That receives as a parameter an array full of non-negative numbers (zero or positive) and sorts the array in the following way:

- In the beginning of the array all the numbers that are divisible by four will appear.
- After them all the numbers in the array that divide by 4 with a remainder of 1 will appear.
- After them all the numbers in the array that divide by 4 with a remainder of 2 will appear.
- In the end of the array all the rest numbers (those which divide by 4 with the remainder 3) will appear.

(The order of the numbers in each group doesn't matter.)

The method must be as efficient as possible.

The following is what I wrote, but unfortunately it doesn't work well... :(

```
public static void swap( int[] arr, int left, int right )
{
    int temp = arr[left];
    arr[left] = arr[right];
    arr[right] = temp;
}

public static void sortByFour( int[] arr )
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = ( arr.length - 1 );
    int mid = ( arr.length / 2 );
    while ( left < right )
    {
        if ( ( arr[left] % 4 ) > ( arr[right] % 4 ) )
        {
            swap( arr, left, right );
            right--;
        }
        if ( ( arr[left] % 4 ) == ( arr[right] % 4 ) )
            left++;
        else
            left++;
    }
}
```

How do I fix or rewrite my code so that it will work well?

Comment: @VeeArr Well, obviously. But it's a good question.

Comment: Correct but I tried to solve it and it doesn't work, that's why I am asking for help.

Comment: My point was, he should tag it with the `homework` tag.

Comment: Why are you using that code? I mean, what's the logic you're trying to achieve there?

Comment: It's what we studied. But I didn't write it well. Can you please fix it?

Comment: That's what you studied but, has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: -1 for asking to have other do your homework. Polygenlubricants and GEShafer gave you already a very good push.

Comment: -1 "Help me figure out what's wrong" and "Fix it for me" (even with a 'please') are very different things.

Comment: The bit at the end, `if(condition) left++; else left++;` is the same as just saying `left++;`, is it not?

Answer (score 2):

I will do this in psuedocode for you but doing it in code would be giving you the answer and this is homework so you can do your own work. =P

Here is how to do it without lists. This example is restricted based on the requirements but will work once you code it.

```
int bucketSize = (arr.length() / 4) + 1;

int bucket1[bucketSize];
int bucket2[bucketSize];
int bucket3[bucketSize];
int bucket4[bucketSize];

for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if ((arr[i] % 4) == 0)
        put arr[i] in bucket 1
    else if ((arr[i] % 4) == 1)
        put arr[i] in bucket 2
    else if ((arr[i] % 4) == 2)
        put arr[i] in bucket 3
    else
        put arr[i] in bucket 4
}

for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    this will go for each bucket
    for (int j=0; j<bucketSize; j++) {
        do sort of your choice here to sort the given bucket
        the sort you used in your code will do fine (the swapping)
    }
}
```

then concatenate the four buckets in their respective order to get your end result

Comment: I also asked my teacher if I can use helper arrays and she said it's not the idea...there must be something more simple and efficient than this.

Comment: First the efficiency is up to how you code it, this is just psuedocode. Second the only way to really get any more efficient than this is to use a true bucket sort as polygenelubricants posted above, but you aren't allowed to use lists. So my suggestion would be if you can write your own list class (Fairly simple) but thats still using a list class, or replace the lists with arrays (as I've shown you)

Comment: instead of using arrays use a system of integers to index your locations in the array and do the same thing...

Comment: Can you please write it so I get the idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can attack the problem like this:

1. Select a sorting algorithm that you wish to use. It looks like you are trying to program [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), but you could also use [Bubble Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).
2. Identify the point(s) of the algorithm where two values from the input array are being compared. For example, in the pseudocode for Bubble Sort on the Wikipedia article, the only comparison is the line `if A[i] > A[i+1] then...`.
3. Figure out a way to compare two numbers so that a number *s* having remainder 0 when divided by 4 is considered less than a number *t* having remainder 1 when divided by 4. Replace the comparison operations of the algorithm with your [comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) calculation (e.g. `if myIsGreater(A[i], A[i+1]) then...`).

For step 3, you are definitely on the right track by considering the modulus operator.

Comment: +1 The requirements for remainder sort order is definitely not the focus of this problem, the comparator will handle that nicely for you.

Answer (score 2):

I will reiterate what Daniel said: you have your choice of sorting algorithm. Use the most efficient one that you've covered in the class so far, if that is the requirement. But when you get to the point in your algorithm where two items are being compared, compare their value mod 4 instead. So something like `if A[i] > A[j]` becomes `if A[i] % 4 > if A[j] % 4`. Then you continue doing whatever the algorithm specifies that you do with that array element. Swap it, bubble it up, return it, whatever is called for.

Regarding the code that you posted, I don't think that it lends itself to a quick fix. Which algorithm is it supposed to be using? What is `mid` there for? I think that once you know which algorithm you intend to use, and figure out which line of code contains the comparison, you will be able to quickly see and code a solution.

In general, with these sorts of things, it can help if you focus on getting a working solution *before* you worry about efficiency. I used selection sort the first time I had to do a problem like this. I would recommend trying that first, and then using the experience gained to do one with merge sort, which is O(n log n).

Answer (score 2):

#### A linear-time solution

The most asymptotically efficient way to do this would be to use [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).

- You have 4 buckets, one for each of the congruency class of numbers modulo 4.
- Scan the numbers in the array once

  - Put each number in the right bucket
- Then construct the output array

  - Put all numbers from bucket 0 first, then all from bucket 1, then bucket 2, then bucket 3

Thus, this sorts the numbers in `O(N)`, which is optimal. The key here is that by sorting on numbers modulo 4, there are essentially only 4 numbers to sort: 0, 1, 2, 3.

---

#### An illustrative solution with `List`

Here's an implementation of the above algorithm (for general modulo `M`) using [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and for-each for clarity. Ignore the unchecked cast warning, just concentrate on understanding the algorithm.

```
import java.util.*;

public class BucketModulo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int M = 4;
        List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(13,7,42,1,6,8,1,4,9,12,11,5);
        List<Integer>[] buckets = (List<Integer>[]) new List[M];
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            buckets[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
        for (int num : nums) {
            buckets[num % M].add(num);
        }
        nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (List<Integer> bucket : buckets) {
            nums.addAll(bucket);
        }
        System.out.println(nums);
        // prints "[8, 4, 12, 13, 1, 1, 9, 5, 42, 6, 7, 11]"
    }
}
```

Once you fully understand the algorithm, translating this to use arrays (if you must) is trivial.

#### See also

- [`java.util.List<E>` API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) - "An ordered collection"

  - [`add(E e)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) - "Appends the specified element to the end of this list"
  - [`addAll(...)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) - "Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list"
- [Java Language Guide/The for-each Loop](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) (introduced in 1.5.0)

---

#### A special note on `%`

The stipulation that numbers are non-negative is significant, because `%` is NOT the *modulo* operator as it's mathematically defined; it's the *remainder* operator.

```
System.out.println(-1 % 2); // prints "-1"
```

#### References

- [JLS 15.17.3 Remainder Operator %](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.17.3)
- [Wikipedia/Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Answer (score 1):

Read this page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Summaries_of_popular_sorting_algorithms

That should help you best in the long run. It's also pretty fun!

Comment: I read it...doesn't help me actually. I will very appreciate it if someone can assist me by fixing my code so that it will work. I am stuck on this question for many hours now.

Comment: If we just fix your code without you understanding WHY it doesn't work, it doesn't help you.

Comment: I know, but when I have the fixed code I will go over it and check why it didn't work before. Explaining me why it doesn't work as well will help me even more.

Comment: @user: your code doesn't work because it's wrong. It's simple as that. There's no easy fix.

Comment: I need a solution in my direction.

Comment: Is like: *Hey, I have this print report system, this is what I have currently* `System.out.println("Hell world")` *please fix it for me to do the rest.*

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Java-ish way...

```
    Arrays.sort(arr,new Comparator<Integer>(){
      public int compare(Integer a,Integer b)
      {
        return (a % 4) - (b % 4);
      }
    });
```

Comment: This shouldn't even be that inefficient, if the integers reside in the integer pool.

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42276