# Sorting arrays in Java using the flag-sort

Tags: java, sorting

Write a static method in Java :

```
public static void sortByFour (int[] arr)
```

That receives as a paramater an array full of non-negative numbers (zero or positive) and sorts the array in the following way :

- In the beginning of the array all the numbers that devide by four without a remainder will appear.
- After them all the numbers in the array that devide by 4 with a remainder of 1 will appear.
- After them all the numbers in the array that devide by 4 with a remainder of 2 will appear.
- In the end of the array all the rest numbers (those who divide by 4 with the remainder 3) will appear.

(The order of the numbers in each group doesn't matter)

The method must be the most efficient as possible using the flag-sort. The space complexity must be **O(1)** and the time complexity must be **O(N)** or less.

**NOTE:** Do NOT use an extra array.

I read about the flag-sort but I don't know how to write the code of it in Java. Can someone please help me?

According to what I read, it is necessary to find the start index and end index in the array of each of the buckets. Is that correct? For this it's necessary to count how many numbers in the array divide by four with a remainder of 0, 1, 2, and 3.

Hmm...

```
public static void sortByFour(int[] arr) {
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0;
    int startB1, startB2, startB3, startB4;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 4 == 0)
            count1++;
        if (arr[i] % 4 == 1)
            count2++;
        if (arr[i] % 4 == 2)
            count3++;
        if (arr[i] % 4 == 3)
            count4++;
    }
    startB1 = 0;
    startB2 = startB1 + count1;
    startB3 = startB2 + count2;
    startB4 = startB3 + count3;

    for (int i = startB1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 4 == 0) {
            swap(arr[i], arr[startB1]);
            startB1++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = startB2; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 4 == 1) {
            swap(arr[i], arr[startB2]);
            startB2++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = startB3; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 4 == 2) {
            swap(arr[i], arr[startB3]);
            startB3++;
        }
    }
}

public static void swap(int a, int b) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

I am not sure it's correct though...

Comment: "... time complexity must be O(N) **or less**" Nice!

Comment: Do you understand the different steps involved in the algorithm? Try to describe each step in pseudo-code. Then break that pseudo-code down into Java code.

Comment: If it's possible to do it in less...

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to write it in java.

Comment: Do you know how to write it in pseudocode? You just need to describe each step in English, which you hopefully know better than Java. Give it a shot and edit the question with the results. It doesn't have to be perfect. With homework, we'd like to see some effort before we help out—you won't learn anything otherwise.

Comment: I am not sure that I know how to write it in pseudocode either. I read about the flag-sort use in a different question but have no idea how to write it in java or fulfill it in this question.

Comment: Please give me instructions on what to do to solve this question and I will try to write the code.

Comment: If you don't give it a go, you won't learn.

Comment: I don't have any idea how to solve this in one loop.

Comment: @yosilacohen: why in one loop? Nothing in the question says you must only use one loop. Looping through the input 3 times can be O(N) as well (if the body of the loop is O(1)). No need to restrict yourself to 1 loop.

Comment: What do you mean the boby of the loop is O(1)? How can a body of the loop be O(1) if it's done over and over again? I am confused

Comment: It's too difficult to me. I need a direction. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting arrays in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992061/sorting-arrays-in-java)

Comment: @yosila: Don't ask the same question again. This is exactly the same as your previous question, and I already helped a lot back then.

Comment: The body of the loop can be O(1) when the time to execute the body **once** doesn't depend on the size of the input (e.g. you don't iterate in it again). Of course, running it N times still means that the **total** time to run the loop is O(N). The important point I was trying to make is that running 3 loops that take O(N) each will still take O(N) in total!

Comment: poly, you used an extra array. And also your space complexity was O(N). This is not allowed. My teacher deducted me 10 points because of this. That's why I asked this question again. Can you please write it in space complexity of O(1) and without using an extra array, using the flag-sort?

Comment: @yosila: okay then, I'll help out again this time. This is going to be more complicated, I warn you.

Comment: Thank you poly. Joachim, I understood you.

Comment: @yosila: i see you edited the question. Is using only 1 loop part of the requirements?

Comment: No it isn't required. As long as the time complexity is O(N) or less than it's ok.

Comment: @yosila: I need an `O(1)` array. Is that okay? Technically you can say that it's not an array and just use a bunch of (a constant number) variables.

Comment: Yes. As long as the space complexity is O(1).

Comment: I edited my question with my work on the first two steps. Isn't it necessary to know the end index of each bucket as well?

Comment: @yosila: Yes, try to read and UNDERSTAND the overview of the algorithm according to Wikipedia.

Comment: @yosila Time complexity cannot be lower than O(N), since each element of the array has to be read, and that alone takes O(N).  Judging from your previous comments I gather you may have a wrong idea about the big-O notation.  Short example: you have 3 loops, you perform 2N ops in the 1st loop, N ops in the 2nd, 2N ops in the 3rd and 17 ops outside the loops.  Total: 5N + 17 ops.  Informally, the total is linear w.r.t. N.  More precisely, there is a constant such that as N goes to ∞, the total does not exceed N times the constant; which means that the total is in O(N).

Comment: @yosila Also, regardless of the context, when you say "O(N) or less" then "or less" is redundant.  It is similar to saying "x <= 7 or less".  What you meant to say was probably "Θ(N) or less", which is exactly "O(N)".

Comment: @yosila: You can't swap like that in Java. Java is pass by value.

Answer (score 5):

#### The algorithm

The sorting algorithm that you need to implement is (a rather obscure one) called the "flag sort". Here's what Wikipedia has to say about it:

> An efficient, in-place variant of radix sort that distributes items into <strike>hundreds of</strike> buckets. The first step counts the number of items in each bucket, and the second step computes where each bucket will start in the array. The last step cyclically permutes items to their proper bucket. Since the buckets are in order in the array, there is no collection step.

In your case:

- There are 4 buckets
- There will be 3 steps (so no, it won't be a single loop solution)
- You need `O(1)` auxiliary space, best as an array, for `count[]`, etc.
- The cyclic permutation is the tricky part, but the first 2 steps is trivial

  - (here's where you can do your part and show some work by doing the first 2 steps)

#### References

- [Wikipedia/American Flag Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_flag_sort)

---

#### Java implementation

Here's the most straightforward implementation of the algorithm that I could do; it also has some logging statement so you can follow the algorithm. You may actually want to skip this part for now and examine the ouput below.

```
static void sort(int... arr) {
   final int M = 4;
   final int N = arr.length;

   int[] count = new int[M];
   for (int num : arr) {
      count[num % M]++;
   } 
   int[] start = new int[M];
   for (int i = 1; i < M; i++) {
      start[i] = start[i-1] + count[i-1];
   }       
   for (int b = 0; b < M; b++) {
      while (count[b] > 0) {
         dump(arr);
         int origin = start[b];
         int from = origin;
         int num = arr[from];
         arr[from] = -1;
         do {
            System.out.printf("Picked up %d from [%d]%n", num, from);
            int to = start[num % M]++;
            count[num % M]--;
            System.out.printf("%d moves from [%d] to [%d]%n", num, from, to);
            int temp = arr[to];
            arr[to] = num;
            num = temp;
            dump(arr);
            from = to;
         } while (from != origin);
      }
   }
}
```

Then we can test it as follows:

```
static void dump(int[] arr) {
    System.out.println("Array is " + java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sort(3, 2, 5, 0, 6, 4, 8, 7, 1, 6);
}
```

This prints:

```
Array is [3, 2, 5, 0, 6, 4, 8, 7, 1, 6]
Picked up 3 from [0]
3 moves from [0] to [8]
Array is [-1, 2, 5, 0, 6, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6]
Picked up 1 from [8]
1 moves from [8] to [3]
Array is [-1, 2, 5, 1, 6, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6]
Picked up 0 from [3]
0 moves from [3] to [0]
Array is [0, 2, 5, 1, 6, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6]
Array is [0, 2, 5, 1, 6, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6]
Picked up 2 from [1]
2 moves from [1] to [5]
Array is [0, -1, 5, 1, 6, 2, 8, 7, 3, 6]
Picked up 4 from [5]
4 moves from [5] to [1]
Array is [0, 4, 5, 1, 6, 2, 8, 7, 3, 6]
Array is [0, 4, 5, 1, 6, 2, 8, 7, 3, 6]
Picked up 5 from [2]
5 moves from [2] to [4]
Array is [0, 4, -1, 1, 5, 2, 8, 7, 3, 6]
Picked up 6 from [4]
6 moves from [4] to [6]
Array is [0, 4, -1, 1, 5, 2, 6, 7, 3, 6]
Picked up 8 from [6]
8 moves from [6] to [2]
Array is [0, 4, 8, 1, 5, 2, 6, 7, 3, 6]
Array is [0, 4, 8, 1, 5, 2, 6, 7, 3, 6]
Picked up 7 from [7]
7 moves from [7] to [9]
Array is [0, 4, 8, 1, 5, 2, 6, -1, 3, 7]
Picked up 6 from [9]
6 moves from [9] to [7]
Array is [0, 4, 8, 1, 5, 2, 6, 6, 3, 7]
```

It may help you understand the algorithm if you go from understanding the output (to see what the algorithm is supposed to do), and then looking at the code (to see how it's done).

#### Attachments

- [source code and output on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/068AA)

Comment: Can you please have a look at the code I wrote? Is it incorrect?

Comment: @yosila: your swap is incorrect. Can't swap like that in Java; it passes by value. If you correct that, then yes, I think it's corrrect. It's not flag sort like Wikipedia explains it, but it's `O(N)` time, `O(1)` space.